# "Your votes are too old to be changed"

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators, election

Now that the [election phase](https://math.stackexchange.com/election) has begun. attempts to click on the "nth choice" buttons beside each candidate result in the titular error message.

What, exactly, is going on?

Comment: It is the election phase, not the primary phase.  The rules for the primary were to have the top 10 advance, and I guess it was determined to be pointless given that there are only 5 candidates.

Comment: Fixed; thanks Jonas.

Comment: I still can't vote, getting the same message J.M. mentions.

Comment: I got a different error, but I would like to point out that they were fixed rather quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anyone having this issue please attempt to vote again.  Thanks!

Comment: It is now fixed (for me at least). Thanks.

Comment: I cast one vote, but deliberated for a long time on my second vote.  Now this error message is preventing me from casting my second or third vote.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for fixing the problem I was having voting. You guys do good quick work!

Comment: @Qiaochu We have expanded the undo window for votes to 4 hours.  Please try again.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to vote as well.